# Trying to query my DB and pass results into an object then to the front, mysql and java

Tags: java, mysql, sql

So currently I am attempted to query my DB and pull out all of the results, make them an object, then push the object to an array of objects, I am having trouble making this work correctly.

work object that has my method as follows

```
public class Table {

    public List<Car> getTableConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Work work = new Work();
        ResultSet result = null;
        Statement sp = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            work.createConnection();
            sp = conn.createStatement();
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            result = sp.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM cardetails");
            while (result.next()) {
                Car car = new Car();
                car.setId(result.getInt("id"));
                car.setYear(result.getString("Year"));
                car.setMake(result.getString("Make"));
                car.setModel(result.getString("Model"));
                car.setColor(result.getString("Color"));
                car.setAvailable(result.getString("Availability"));
                cars.add(car);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        } finally {

        }
        return cars;
    }
}
```

and when I am reaching to pull those objects out on my JSP I'm doing this.

```
<%  
    Table table = new Table();
    table.getTableConnection();
    List<Car> cars = table.getTableConnection();
    String renting;
    for (Car c : cars) {
        int id = c.getId();
        String year = c.getYear();
        String make = c.getMake();
        String model = c.getModel();
        String color = c.getColor();
        String avail = c.getAvailable();
    }
%>
```

Currently I'm getting no errors but it seems my results I'm getting back is nothing while querying the DB.

Comment: you are not displaying them ?? do you have data in table ? what's your issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Table {

public List<Car> getTableConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    Work work = new Work();
    ResultSet result = null;
    Statement sp = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        **conn =work.createConnection();**
        sp = conn.createStatement();
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        result = sp.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM cardetails");
        while (result.next()) {
            Car car = new Car();
            car.setId(result.getInt("id"));
            car.setYear(result.getString("Year"));
            car.setMake(result.getString("Make"));
            car.setModel(result.getString("Model"));
            car.setColor(result.getString("Color"));
            car.setAvailable(result.getString("Availability"));
            cars.add(car);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    } finally {

    }
    return cars;
}
```

}